# Solving password's task in python

Tags: python

I have tried to solve this task but can't find what is wrong with my code.

I didn't succeed. I would like to find where exactly I am wrong and why. Also, I know it is possible to solve in another way but want to understand what is wrong with my code

The task is about:
ATM machines allow 4 or 6 digit PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digits.

If the function is passed a valid PIN string, return true, else return false.

My code:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    if len(pin) != 4 or len(pin) != 6:
        return False
    else:
        return pin.isdigit()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. Remember, we can't help you if we can't see what you've tried.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with this code? What part doesn't work as expected?

Comment: `if len(pin) != 4 or len(pin) != 6` - Can you think of any possible value for `pin` in which this overall condition could be `False`?

Comment: The problem is that if the length of the PIN is **4**, it necessarily *isn't* **6**...so this will never be true.

Comment: @Natasha The if condition should instead be `len(pin) != 4 and len(pin) != 6`. Or, if you prefer, `not (len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6)`.

Comment: @BenGrossmann isn't `len(pin) != 4 or len(pin) != 6` what's written here?

Comment: @JRiggles Gah good catch

Comment: @BenGrossmann No worries - just wanted to make sure I wasn't losing it! hahaha

Comment: Seems like the test should be "if len(pin) != 4 and len(pin) !=6:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is with the boolean logic including negatives as well as an or.

You want "the pin must be 4 digits or 6 digits. if it is neither, it is bad". But notice in the way I phrased it in normal language, the logic each time is equals, rather than not-equals, and using the "or".

You have your comparisons here as not-equals, which is fine, but then you need "and", not "or". You should have:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    if len(pin) != 4 and len(pin) != 6:
        return False
    else:
        return pin.isdigit()
```

Put more generally, given the statement `P or Q` (both true), the negation of this is `~P and ~Q` (the little ~ meaning 'not').

I'm pretty sure this is [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

edit: add everything below here

To make this easier to parse, the best course of action is probably to just make the boolean logic more intuitive but checking that it is what you want (rather than checking that it isn't).

```py
def validate_pin(pin):
    if len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6:
        return pin.isdigit()
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you only want to permit PINs of length 4 or 6, you can refactor your `if` condition like so:

```
if len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6:
    return pin.isdigit()
else:
    return False
```

Technically, in this case you don't even need the `else` clause, but that's up to you.

```
if len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6:
    return pin.isdigit()
return False
```

The other option is to change your `or` to `and`, which will check if `len(pin)` *isn't* 4 **and** *isn't* 6

Comment: `False` not `false` in Python.

Comment: @slothrop Good catch, thanks! I've been over in Javascipt-land for a few months so I'm getting my wires crossed

Answer (score 0):

As other's answer has pointing out the problem about `or` & `and` operator (Guard condition for length of pin is not 4 `or` is not 6 will cause pin with length of 4 is returning false due to matches with guard length pin is not 6 - always return false) . You might use both operator in one line:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    return (len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6) and pin.isdigit()
```